# No se muestra sitio web en Firefox

Tags: certificado-ssl

Buenas tardes tengo un sitio web con sello de seguridad SSL, anteriormente no me marcaba error y se podía visualizar el sitio web en todos los navegadores, pero ahora me está marcado error el sitio web cuando se visualiza en Firefox.

Les anexo el error que me manda la el sitio web y la liga.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[www.abacom.mx](https://www.abacom.mx)

Espero que me puedan apoyar.
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sec_error_revoked_certificate` significa que el certificado fue [revocado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list).

Tu certificado puede que haya sido emitido por una entidad certificadora o **CA** que era de confianza para tu navegador en un momento del pasado, pero ahora mismo la entidad certificadora lo revocó y tu navegador está configurado para revisar si un certificado fue revocado.

Normalmente, estas situaciones se dan cuando ha habido problemas en la **CA** y deben revocar certificados intermedios u otros elementos del proceso de certificación. Han habido casos en los que se comprometen algunos de estos certificados intermedios y deben ser revocados, evitando así que terceros inescrupulosos no los usen para suplantar sitios legítimos.

[El SSL checker de Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) es una herramienta útil para hacer estas validaciones, emulando la validación de certificados como lo haría un navegador moderno.

Añado un fragmento de la validación en el SSL Checker. De paso, vale la pena renovarlo y configurar de nuevo tu interfaz HTTPS para que el sitio no esté sujeto a viejas vulnerabilidades como POODLE o BEAST

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12376621/236345)